# How to add double click event in node react-diagram

Tags: javascript, reactjs, diagram

I want to add double click event on each node of my diagram and do something when that happened, but I've just seen the selectionChanged event, do you know how to extends from the class node and customize my node and add this event or any other way?

```
node.registerListener({
    selectionChanged: e => //doSomething,
    doubleClickEvent: e => //doSomethingFromMyCustomMethod 
});
```

Thanks